# HTML table with Client side scripting to store in Mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I had created a `table` in **PHP** from **MySQL** database with some calculations. Need to store the output of **HTML** `table` in database new `table`.

```
 <table>  
   <tr>  
     <th>slno</th>
     <th>util%</th>
     <th>empid</th>
     <th>Name</th>
    </tr>  
    <tr>
     <td>1</td> 
     <td><div id= "util1"></div></td>
     <td>5001</td>
     <td>name1</td>
    </tr>  
    <tr>
     <td>2</td>
     <td><div id= "util2"></div></td>
     <td>5002</td>
     <td>name2</td>
    </tr>  
    <tr>
     <td>3</td>
     <td><div id= "util3"></div></td>
     <td>5003</td>
     <td>name3</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: share some code please

Comment: @sampath ,share what you have tried

Comment: util% is calcuated in script    <script>$(document).ready(function(){   document.getElementById('util1').innerHTML = 30;document.getElementById('util2').innerHTML = 20;document.getElementById('util3').innerHTML = 40;</script>

Answer (score -1):

get HTML by ID.

```
 $("#id").html();
```

Pass this html in ajax call and get this on php page.

```
 var a='{"functioncd":"storelayout","html":"'+ $("id").html()+'"}';

 var url="store.php";       
    request = $.ajax({
      dataType: 'text',
   type: "POST",
   async : false,
    url: url,
     data:{str:a}
 });
```